# Scala Futures with DB

Tags: postgresql, scala, future

I'm writing code in scala/play with anorm/postgres for match generation based on users profiles. The following code works, but I've commented out the section that is causing problems, the `while` loop. I noticed while running it that the first 3 Futures seem to work synchronously but the problem comes when I'm retrieving the count of rows in the table in the fourth step.

The fourth step returns the count before the above insert's actually happened. As far as I can tell, steps 1-3 are being queued up for postgres synchronously, but the call to retrieve the count seems to return BEFORE the first 3 steps complete, which makes no sense to me. If the first 3 steps get queued up in the correct order, why wouldn't the fourth step wait to return the count until after the inserts happen?

When I uncomment the while loop, the match generation and insert functions are called until memory runs out, as the count returned is continually below the desired threshold.

I know the format itself is subpar, but my question is not about how to write the most elegant scala code, but merely how to get it to work for now.

```
def matchGeneration(email:String,itNum:Int) = {
  var currentIterationNumber = itNum
  var numberOfMatches = MatchData.numberOfCurrentMatches(email)
    while(numberOfMatches < 150){
          Thread.sleep(25000)//delay while loop execution time
          generateUsers(email) onComplete {
            case(s) => {
               print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 1")
               Thread.sleep(5000)//Time for initial user generation to take place
              genDemoMatches(email, currentIterationNumber) onComplete {
                case (s) => {
                  print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 2")
                  genIntMatches(email,currentIterationNumber) onComplete {
                    case(s) => {
                      print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 3")
                      genSchoolWorkMatches(email,currentIterationNumber) onComplete {
                        case(s) => {
                          Thread.sleep(10000)
                          print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 4")
                          incrementNumberOfMatches(email) onComplete {
                            case(s) => {
                              currentIterationNumber+=1
                              println(s"current number of matches: $numberOfMatches")
                              println(s"current Iteration: $currentIterationNumber")
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        //}
  }
```

The match functions are defined as futures, such as :

```
def genSchoolWorkMatches(email:String,currentIterationNumber:Int):Future[Unit]=
Future(genUsersFromSchoolWorkData(email, currentIterationNumber))
```

`genUsersFromSchoolWorkData(email:String)` follows the same form as the other two. It is a function that initially gets all the school/work fields that a user has filled out in their profile ( `SELECT major FROM school_work where email='$email'`) and it generates a dummyUser that contains one of those fields in common with this user of `email:String`. It would take about 30-40 lines of code to print this function so I can explain it further if need be.

I have edited my code, the only way I found so far to get this to work was by hacking it with `Thread.sleep()`. I think the problem may lie with anorm 
 as my Future logic constructs did work as I expected, but the problem lies in the inconsistency of when writes occur versus what the read returns. The `numberOfCurrentMatches(email:String)` function returns the number of matches as it is a simple `SELECT count(email) from table where email='$email'`. The problem is that sometimes after inserting 23 matches the count returns as 0, then after a second iteration it will return 46. I assumed that the onComplete() would bind to the underlying anorm function defined with `DB.withConnection()` but apparently it may be too far removed to accomplish this. I am not really sure at this point what to research or look up further to try to get around this problem, rather than writing a separate sort of supervisor function to return at a value closer to 150.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the advice of user's here, and trying to understand Scala's documentation at this link: [Scala Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#in_a_future)

I have updated my code to be a bit more readable and scala-esque:

```
  def genMatchOfTypes(email:String,iterationNumber:Int) = {
    genDemoMatches(email,iterationNumber)
    genIntMatches(email,iterationNumber)
    genSchoolWorkMatches(email,iterationNumber)
  }
  def matchGeneration(email:String) = {
  var currentIterationNumber = 0
  var numberOfMatches = MatchData.numberOfCurrentMatches(email)
  while (numberOfMatches < 150) {
    println(s"current number of matches: $numberOfMatches")
    Thread.sleep(30000)
    generateUsers(email)
      .flatMap(users =>  genMatchOfTypes(email,currentIterationNumber))
      .flatMap(matches => incrementNumberOfMatches(email))
      .map{
          result =>
            currentIterationNumber += 1
            println(s"current Iteration2: $currentIterationNumber")
            numberOfMatches = MatchData.numberOfCurrentMatches(email)
            println(s"current number of matches2: $numberOfMatches")
        }
    }

  }
```

I still am heavily dependent upon the `Thread.sleep(30000)` to provide enough time to run through the while loop before it tries to loop back again. It's still an unwieldy hack. When I uncomment the `Thread.sleep()`

my output in bash looks like this:

```
users for match generation createdcurrent number of matches: 0
[error] c.MatchDataController - here is the list: jnkj
[error] c.MatchDataController - here is the list: hbhjbjjnkjn
current number of matches: 0
current number of matches: 0
current number of matches: 0
current number of matches: 0
current number of matches: 0
```

This of course is a truncated output. It runs like this over and over until I get errors about too many open files and the JVM/play server crashes entirely.

Comment: *is now about* should be read *is not about* ?

Comment: @Odomontois yes sorry was typing quickly will edit

Comment: Important question. Is `currentIterationNumber` will be allways increased in successful future branch or there could be some conditions?

Comment: You could chain the futures via `fold` and `andThen`.

Comment: Can you include the definition of the functions `genSchoolWorkMatches` and `incrementNumberOfMatches` in your question?

Comment: @Odomontois in regards to your question about currentIterationNumber:
it should always be incremented after the four Futures complete, as I use this number to point to the next row of results in the gen*Matches function calls, i.e. when it is 0 it retrieves the first row 1, the second, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `Future.traverse` for known iteration count

Implying

```
object MatchData {
  def numberOfCurrentMatches(email: String) = ???
}

def generateUsers(email: String): Future[Unit] = ???
def incrementNumberOfMatches(email: String): Future[Int] = ???
def genDemoMatches(email: String, it: Int): Future[Unit] = ???
def genIntMatches(email: String, it: Int): Future[Unit] = ???
def genSchoolWorkMatches(email: String, it: Int): Future[Unit] = ???
```

You can write code like

```
def matchGeneration(email: String, itNum: Int) = {
  val numberOfMatches = MatchData.numberOfCurrentMatches(email)
  Future.traverse(Stream.range(itNum, 150 - numberOfMatches + itNum)) { currentIterationNumber => for {
    _ <- generateUsers(email)
    _ = print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 1")
    _ <- genDemoMatches(email, currentIterationNumber)
    _ = print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 2")
    _ <- genIntMatches(email, currentIterationNumber)
    _ = print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 3")
    _ <- genSchoolWorkMatches(email, currentIterationNumber)
    _ = Thread.sleep(15000)
    _ = print(s">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STEP 4")
    numberOfMatches <- incrementNumberOfMatches(email)
    _ = println(s"current number of matches: $numberOfMatches")
    _ = println(s"current Iteration: $currentIterationNumber")
  } yield ()
  }
```

#### Update

If you urged to check some condition each time, one way is to use cool monadic things from [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). It have definition of monad for `scala.Future` so we can replace word *monadic* with *asynchronous* when we want to

For example `StreamT.unfoldM` can create conditional monadic(asynchronous) loop, even if we don need elements of resulting collection we still can use it just for iteration.

Lets define your

```
def generateAll(email: String, iterationNumber: Int): Future[Unit] = for {
  _ <- generateUsers(email)
  _ <- genDemoMatches(email, iterationNumber)
  _ <- genIntMatches(email, iterationNumber)
  _ <- genSchoolWorkMatches(email, iterationNumber)
} yield ()
```

Then iteration step

```
def generateStep(email: String, limit: Int)(iterationNumber: Int): Future[Option[(Unit, Int)]] =
  if (MatchData.numberOfCurrentMatches(email) >= limit) Future(None)
  else for {
    _ <- generateAll(email, iterationNumber)
    _ <- incrementNumberOfMatches(email)
    next = iterationNumber + 1
  } yield Some((), next)
```

Now our resulting function simplifies to

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._

def matchGeneration(email: String, itNum: Int): Future[Unit] =
  StreamT.unfoldM(0)(generateStep(email, 150) _).toStream.map(_.force: Unit)
```

It looks like synchronous method `MatchData.numberOfCurrentMatches` is reacting on your asynchronous modification inside the `incrementNumberOfMatches`. Note that generally it could lead to disastrous results and you probably need to move that state inside some [actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html) or something like that

Comment: this is very useful information thank you but my problem is that i won't know how many iterations each user will require to generate 150 fake matches for themselves. if user A has 30 fields to be matched on, it will take 5 iterations where as if user B has 50 fields to be matched on, it will take only 3 iterations.

Comment: this looks incredible but will take me a bit of time to absorb.. haha. am going to have to pore over it for a bit !

Comment: Yes I figured the major flaw in my logic was the use of a variable counter and the use of futures and inconsistent values of that variable across different threads